# Custom round checkbox in Bootstrap popover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

I try use this custom round checkbox

```css
.round {
  position: relative;
}

.round label {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 28px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
}

.round label:after {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  content: "";
  height: 6px;
  left: 7px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #66bb6a;
  border-color: #66bb6a;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f2f3;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="round">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want this add to bootstrap popover whit html content

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#order-popover').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
    }
  }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {});
});
```

```css
.round {
  position: relative;
}

.round label {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 28px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
}

.round label:after {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  content: "";
  height: 6px;
  left: 7px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #66bb6a;
  border-color: #66bb6a;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f2f3;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="#" id="order-popover" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom">OPEN</a>
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display:none;">
  <div style="width: 100px;">
    <div class="round">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
      <label for="checkbox"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I add this in to bootstrap popover checkbox not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because your popover html is created at the time of click thats why your `for` attribute is not working...

So you will need to put your checkbox input in front of label using `position:relative` and some `z-index` with `opacity:0` to hide it

***Note***: If you will remove the `for` attribute it will also work, but write it for better readability

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#order-popover').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
    }
  }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {});

});
```

```css
.round {
  position: relative;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
}

.round label {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 28px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
}

.round label:after {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  content: "";
  height: 6px;
  left: 7px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #66bb6a;
  border-color: #66bb6a;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f2f3;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="#" id="order-popover" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom">OPEN</a>
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display:none;">
  <div style="width: 100px;">
    <div class="round">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" />
      <label for="checkbox3"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```